# Spark : how to create productiuon job for spark processing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql to run the job and what should be the production command ?
can i use spark-sql as production job command ?

Thanks,
Virendra

Comment: Do you have a production cluster? Or are you just intending to use data from databases in "production systems"?

Comment: yes I have production cluster. mostly to query and see the performace of query with multiple joins i use SPARK-SQL. so can use same SPARK-SQl in production also for daily bsais run? or should i use SPAR-SUBMIT ? the problem is to use SPARK-SUBMIT i have to write scala or java code and create JAR which can be used in SPARK-SUBMIT.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what's your meaning of production. Could you elaborate it a bit more?

spark-sql is designed for interactive explore the data. It launch a java process as a REPL.

Perhaps put the code in a maven project is more straight forward. Like [this](https://github.com/rockiey/explore-spark)

Comment: Thanks ! I am not programming guy so wanted to work more with SQL type feature which SPARK-SQL has but to submit regular basis job in production cluster do i must have JAR (scala/java code base) or with only  SPARK-SQL i can run my Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use *SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit* to run you code on cluster. More information you can find here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: Thanks ! it means i have to write code in scala or java and call sqlContext. then create jar and use SPARK-SUBMIT. but is there anyway that with Only SPARK-SQL i can create job and call my script (sql) as parameter.?

Comment: I don't think so. You should create uber jar and deploy to cluster.